# How do I make my data structure more efficient?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures

I'm developing a new data structure that theoretically is more efficient than a hashmap. It does this by having an O(1) resize when there is a collision. The issue is that when inserting data(the metric I care most about), it is slightly slower than a hashmap when it should be significantly faster.

here is all the code used in the insert:

```
private void insert(Pair data, SwitchArray currTable){
    if (currTable.isExpanded == false && currTable.iValue==null) { //checks the very first iValue
        currTable.iValue = data;
        return;
    }
    else if (!currTable.isExpanded) {// if there is a new colision
        SwitchArray[] x = new SwitchArray[currTable.primeArray[currTable.depth]];
        currTable.sA = x;
        Integer index= Math.abs(data.key.hashCode()) % currTable.sA.length;
        currTable.sA[index] = new SwitchArray(data, currTable.depth+1);
        currTable.isExpanded = true;
        insert(currTable.iValue,currTable);
        currTable.iValue = null;
    }
    else{ // if expanded
        Integer index= Math.abs(data.key.hashCode()) % currTable.sA.length;
        if (currTable.sA[index] == null){
            currTable.sA[index] = new SwitchArray(data, currTable.depth+1); //this updates ivalue in the constructor
        } else {
            currTable = currTable.sA[index];
            insert(data,currTable);//go one level deeper

        }
    }
}
```

these are the two subclasses I refrence

```
class SwitchArray{
        int depth;
        int length;
        SwitchArray[] sA;
        Pair iValue;
        int[] primeArray = new int[]{7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37};
        boolean isExpanded = false;
        
        public SwitchArray(Pair iValue, int depth){
            this.iValue = iValue;
            this.depth = depth;
            length = primeArray[depth];
            if (iValue != null)
                iValue.myDepth = depth;
            
        }
        
    }
```

```
class Pair{
    String key;
    Integer value;
    int myDepth;
    
    public Pair(String key, Integer value){
        this.key=key;
        this.value=value;
        myDepth = -1;
    }
    
    public String toString(){
        return "( " + key + ", " + value + " | depth: " + myDepth + ")";
    }

}
```

[here is the code in its entirety](https://github.com/william4356/Data-structures-junoir/blob/main/final%20Project/MDHT.java)

I have [tested the efficiency](https://github.com/william4356/Data-structures-junoir/blob/main/final%20Project/MDHTEfficiencyTester.java) by adding varying amounts of data (from 1 pair all the way until I got a Java heap space error) to both hashmaps and my MDHT, and graphed them by using excel. Consistantly MDHTs are slightly slower.

(I would like to also add that this is just a fun project I am doing, not trying to overthrow hashmaps or anything.)

So the question I ask you is how do I fix it or slightly improve it at least?

Comment: To make sure I understand the strategy you’re using, at a high level: begin at the top level. If the top slot is free, fill it. Otherwise, recursively descend into the slot corresponding to the hash code and try placing the element there. Is that correct?

Comment: @templatetypedef yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

> new SwitchArray[currTable.primeArray[currTable.depth]];

This is relatively slow as it needs to clear out the new array. You can't opt of this, although hotspot tends to recognize any array whose values are almost immediately guaranteed entirely filled up, and omits the initial writing of zeroes into the heap for it. This doesn't apply here and isn't an optimization that seems possible to add here.

> `insert`

This method is recursive, and the number of times it recurses is related to the amount of collisions you have, therefore, it isn't `O(1)`.

> So the question I ask you is how do I fix it or slightly improve it at least?

HashMap wasn't written by some random moron. It's possibly not perfect but a rote algorithmic complexity improvement is not available. You may be able to build a theoretical improvement in basic opcode count, but this is extremely unlikely to beat hashmap. The reason? Hotspot.

The hotspot engine is a gigantic pattern matcher. It finds patterns that it knows how to optimize and optimizes them. Whilst it does all sorts of magic in order to recognize as many patterns as it can, there is one simple fundamental truth: **It recognizes idiomatic java**. This library of patterns to optimize isn't built based on 'what sequence of opcodes can I optimize?'. It's built on a much simpler notion than that: 'Which sequence of opcodes is commonly observed in java code?'

In other words, commonly used patterns are better optimized. And HashMap is *very* commonly used. Hence:

- Your notion that you can do `O(1)` insertion when there are collisions is certainly possible, but you can't guarantee `O(1)` lookup by fundamental definitions. However, as a general rule, as long as you aren't overloading on collisions, that isn't the controlling performance issue. At small `n`, an `O(n)` algorithm and an `O(n^2)` algorithm are simply **unrelated**. The algorithmically slower algorithm will beat the faster one, or not - the point is, the algorithmic complexity is completely meaningless until n is 'large enough'. When is 'large enough'? Depends on the hardware, the algorithm, the data, and the phase of the moon - the point of big-O notation isn't to predict when 'large enough' is reached, merely to posit that there is SOME n, could be incredulously large, when the algorithmic complexity 'takes over' and accurately predicts the faster algorithm. Point is, with hashmaps, most likely either:

[A] This is an academic case where you add thousands of objects with clashing hashcodes. Who gives a piddle what the performance of anything is at this point? The fix is to address the broken hash impl, not to futz about trying to shine the turd. lookups are guaranteed to be `O(n)` in this case and the primary point of a hashmap is to faster than that. Just use `ArrayList` in this case, you can't beat its performance then. It has `O(1)` inserts and `O(n)` lookups. Besides, your code will just crash if you try; your buckets are limited to at most 37 items. A map with 37 items in it is **far** to the left of that magical fulcrum point where 'n' becomes relevant.

[B] There aren't a ton of collisions. `n` is simply not large enough for algorithmic complexity to matter.

And also:

- Trying to improve on things by just 'writing it slightly more optimized' is doomed to failure: The 'judge' (the hotspot VM) is biased because HashMap is so common, all hotspot implementations are designed to recognize the bytecode in j.u.HashMap and optimize it. You may be able to do some theoretic improvements but they will be small; too small to outweigh the penalty of this biased judge.

CONCLUSION: It's not possible to improve HashMap's performance without adding significant caveats to the data you intend to store in your BetterHashMap. In other words, any generalized hashmap that is significantly better than j.u.HM in some regards and not significantly worse in others is an extraordinary job and likely impossible.